# Find the value of $a$ for which the cubic polynomial has integral roots.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, polynomials

Given that the equation $x^3 – 75x + a = 0$ has three integral roots $r_1$, $r_2$ and $r_3$ (where $a \in I$), then $|r_1| + |r_2| + |r_3|$ is equal to?

I first tried to graph the function by finding it's local maxima and local minima. I got that the local minima and maxima are at $-5$ and $5$ respectively. I then looked at the $y$ value of those points. They were respectively. Now by hit and trial, I got that $a=250$ was a possible solution which gave me the correct answer of 20.

However, I am not satisfied. I tried using Cardano's formula and the cubic discriminant to see if I could place restrictions on $a$ or $r_1.r_2,r_3$. It became so messy that I left it midway. Can anybody provide me with a rigorous proof as to why only $a=250$ is a solution or if there are more values for $a$.

Comment: What is $I$? Can $a$ be any real number?

Comment: $I$ is the set of all integers.

Answer (score 2):

Let $m,n,p$ the three integral roots; we get $m+n+p=0, m^2+n^2+p^2=150$ so $m^2+n^2+mn=75$ where wlog we can assume $m \ge n \ge 0, p <0$ (since $m,n,p \to -m,-n,-p$ doesn't change anything and clearly two roots have the same sign and the third oposite from the zero sum); this means $3n^2 \le 75$ so $1 \le n \le 5$ and by an easy checking only $n=m=5, p=-10$ so $a =\pm 250$ give you integral roots.